# New “Metier” is created when editing a “Metier”

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

When I try to edit a "Metier", a new "Metier" is created and the old one stays the same. I want to crush the old "Metier" and create a new one just by editing. Here is my code in relation with the edit function.

**Controller**

```
 public function edit($id)
{
$metier=Metier::find($id);
return view('metier.edit',['libelle_metier'=>$metier]);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
$metier=Metier::find($id);
return view('metier.edit',['libelle_metier'=>$metier]);
}
```

**View**

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="">libelle Metier </label>
 <input type="text"  name ="libelle_metier" class="form-control"value ="
 {{$libelle_metier->libelle_metier}}" >
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form-control btn btn-
 primary">
 </div>
```

**route**

```
Route::get('/metier', 'MetierController@index');
Route::get('/metier/create', 'MetierController@create');
Route::post('/metier', 'MetierController@store');
Route::get('/metier/{id}/show', 'MetierController@edit');
Route::get('/metier/{id}/edit', 'MetierController@edit');
Route::upd('/metier/{id}/update', 'MetierController@update');
Route::delete('/metier/{id}', 'MetierController@destroy')
```

**MetierController.php**

```
public function edit($id)
{
$metier=Metier::find($id);
return view('metier.edit',['libelle_metier'=>$metier]);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $metier = Metier::find($id);
    $metier->libelle_metier = $request->libelle_metier;
    $metier->save();
    return back();
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Modifier Metier </h1>

        <form action=" {{url ('metier')  }}" method="post">
            {{csrf_field()}}



            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="">libelle Metier </label>
             <input type="text"  name ="libelle_metier" class="form-
control"value ="
             {{$libelle_metier->libelle_metier}}" >
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
             <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form-control 
btn btn-
             primary">
             </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `{{ method_field('PATCH') }}` to your form and change action to named route and pass metier id to it.

```
 @extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Modifier Metier </h1>

        <form action="{{ route('metier.update', $libelle_metier->id) }}" method="post">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            {{ method_field('PATCH') }}



            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="">libelle Metier </label>
             <input type="text"  name ="libelle_metier" class="form-
control"value ="
             {{$libelle_metier->libelle_metier}}" >
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
             <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form-control 
btn btn-
             primary">
             </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Route file

```
Route::patch('/metier/{id}/update', 'MetierController@update')->name('metier.update');
```

**Hint:** delete all these

```
Route::get('/metier', 'MetierController@index');
Route::get('/metier/create', 'MetierController@create');
Route::post('/metier', 'MetierController@store');
Route::get('/metier/{id}/show', 'MetierController@edit');
Route::get('/metier/{id}/edit', 'MetierController@edit');
Route::upd('/metier/{id}/update', 'MetierController@update');
Route::delete('/metier/{id}', 'MetierController@destroy')
```

and either add just it all as a single resource, so that all REST urls will be added in one shot.
this is how should be if its REST specification. read it 
[REST Resource Naming Guide](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/) and [here](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/REST)

```
Route::resource('metier', 'MetierController');
```

or add it this way instead of resource

```
Route::get('/metier', 'MetierController@index')->name('metier.index');
Route::get('/metier/create', 'MetierController@create')->name('metier.create');
Route::post('/metier', 'MetierController@store')->name('metier.store');
Route::get('/metier/{id}', 'MetierController@show')->name('metier.show');
Route::get('/metier/{id}/edit', 'MetierController@edit')->name('metier.edit');
Route::patch('/metier/{id}', 'MetierController@update')->name('metier.update');
Route::delete('/metier/{id}', 'MetierController@destroy')->name('metier.destroy');
```

Learn about [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers)

Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $metier=Metier::find($id);
    return view('metier.edit',['libelle_metier'=>$metier]);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // do some request validation
    $metier=Metier::find($id);
    $metier->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('metier.show', $metier->id);
}
```

if you are having mass assignment error.

add `protected $guarded = [];` to the Metier model

Comment: my bad.now its been fixed

Comment: brought some changes

Comment: with this i've got a route issue

Comment: sorry with this solution i've got "_token"

Comment: updated answer with  REST resource url specification

Comment: @aimme where exactly should i add protected $guarded = []; please ?

Comment: Mitier.php the model file class Metier extends Model { protected $guarded=[]; ....... there

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't even try to update the DB record. Do something like this instead:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    Metier::where('id', $id)->update($request->all());
    return back();
}
```

Or without using the mass assignment:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $metier = Metier::find($id);
    $metier->libelle_metier = $request->libelle_metier;
    $metier->save();
    return back();
}
```

**Update**

Thanks for sharing the whole form. You're also using `POST` method instead of `PUT`. Change the form URL and add this field to the form:

```
<form action="{{ url('metier/' . $libelle_metier->id . '/update')  }}" method="post">
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Then the `update()` method will be executed instead of `store()`.

And change the route to `put`:

```
Route::put('/metier/{id}/update', 'MetierController@update');
```

Also, it's a good idea to use `Route::resource` instead of manually creating the same routes. It will allow you to avoid this kind of errors.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-method-field

Comment: i've tried both solutions i keep getting "Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException
_token"

Comment: @IT2704 with seconds solution you will not get this error. For the first one, use `$request->except('_token')` or `$request->only('libelle_metier')`

Comment: yes there is no more error with this solution but the problem is not solved because a new "Metier" is created whenever I make the edit

Comment: @IT2704 the code I've shown can't create a new record. Please show full form.

Comment: @IT2704 I've updated the answer. You need to change some other code to make it work.

Comment: route issue the form page could no more be displayed